# PHPSTORM intellisense for casted object

Tags: php, oop, intellisense, phpstorm

I've got an object `News` which has some public properties. I am casting this object to an array and passing to the file to be rendered. I wonder is there a way to create a phpdoc to the news object, that is casted to an array, so there was an intellisense. If this feature was not implemented where can I give the suggestion to the community, so they considered this issue?

**Some example code:**

Model:

```
/**
 * @property string $content
 */
class News extends ActiveRecord {
  public $date;
  ...
}
```

Controller:

```
...
$news = new News();
...
$news = (array)$news
$this->render('news_page',compact('news'));
...
```

View:

```
/**
 * @var News $news
 */
// here should go intellisense for property content and date when pressing ctrl+space
echo $news['content'];
...
```

Thanks!

**Update**
It turned out that this feature is not implemented, so I created an issue on jetbrains web-site. Link here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26323. If you agree with me please vote up my issue.

Comment: Array contents aren't hinted at all, AFAIK. Why not keep it an object instead of casting it to an array?

Comment: @deceze you are wrong actually, create a multidimensional array like so: $a = ['b'=>'c']; and try to access its keys! woala it works!

Comment: I stand corrected. This only seems to work within the same scope though, since there's no defined data structure as such. If you pass the array elsewhere, it's unpredictable what contents it will have, beyond being able to say that it's an "array". So, I doubt there's a way to do what you want.

Comment: @deceze that is why we have phpdocs. if some key does not exists it should be the problem of developer to validate it, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think this can be done. I know that you can annotate magic methods, but I haven't seen someone annotating the possible keys in an associative array. The place to ask would be the JetBrains support.

Comment: Why can you just access it as field instead (i.e. `$news->content` ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot hint custom array keys via PHPDoc (be it key name itself or value type) -- currently it's not supported.

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3423
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5304

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) and possibly some of the related tickets to get notified on progress.

Comment: These issues are not identical. Created a new issue. Link here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26323. Would be happy if someone votes for it.

Comment: Since when `@property` is used for array key completion? Any links to PHPDoc documentation that confirms that? In any case: you have filled a ticket so now it's up to PhpStorm devs to decide what they plan to do about it.